# Taking screenshots of the client side using javascript

Tags: javascript, screenshot, screen-capture

I have tried a service like html2canvas, which traverses the DOM and renders a canvas element, but its output is not precise with more complex websites. Is there any way I can programmatically produce an exact replica of what the client of my website is seeing using javascript, such as what is done in grabz.it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

Comment: Actually 2 cases you mentioned are quite different. While html2canvas use client-side rendering to canvas, grabz.it use server-side rendering for their service (that mean their server will fetch the website and render it). Server-side rendering always easier to achieve since you totally control your server. For client-side rendering I afraid there's just a few options for you, namely canvas rendering like html2canvas or similar approaches, and using some old libraries which is based on flash (not sure if they're still possible now due to strictly policy that browsers nowaday apply to flash)